# Redirect html files web.xml (servlet)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, web.xml

I want to redirect html files on my web.xml file, but how?

First of all,I use Google App Engine and I have this hierarchy for my html files

/war/myweb/index.html

I want to visit www.mydomain.com and access to /war/myweb/index.html, but how do I configure my web.xml file? example:

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>AdminAddCountry</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.myDomain.api.admin.AddCountryAdmin</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AdminAddCountry</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/admin/v1/api/addcountry</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Of course, I know if I put the index.html file in /war I will access by www.mydomain.com to index.html

Thanks

Comment: You mean to say that when you go to mydomain.com it should read the index.html from war/myweb/index.html?? for this you want to configure your web.xml?

Comment: And why don't you do the simplest thing: move the file to the appropriate location?

Comment: Yes Sandiip Patil, or maybe I have to configure another file?
JB Nizet because I got a lot of files and I want to be tidy